# Struggling with implementing a Monad function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

Recently, I'm playing around with Haskell monad and trying to learn about this concept.

Let's say there is a tree data type declared which can have multiple sub-trees.

```
data MyTree a = MyTree a [MyTree a]
```

And I'm trying to implement a function that returns "Nothing" if the tree contains any "Nothing" value in the tree. Else, extract all m value and returns a wrapped tree.

So the function type signature has the following.

```
check :: Monad m => MyTree (m a) -> m (MyTree a)
```

And here is my current implementation.

```
check (MyTree v []) = v >>= (\v' -> return (MyTree v' []))
check (MyTree v (x:xs)) =
  v >>= (\v' -> check x >>= (\t' -> return (MyTree v' [t'])))
```

I use a bind operator on v so that I can get a pure value of it. Then I call the "check" function recursively with the head value from the list. Finally, I wrap the final results.

I tested with some samples and got the following results.

```
> test1 = MyTree (Just 1) [MyTree (Just 2) [MyTree (Just 3) []]]
> check test1
Just (MyTree 1 [MyTree 2 [MyTree 3 []]])

> test2 = MyTree (Just 1) [MyTree (Just 2) [], MyTree (Just 3) []]
> check test2
-- expected: Just (MyTree 1 [MyTree 2 [], MyTree 3 []]
-- actual:   Just (MyTree 1 [MyTree 2 []])
```

So, the current implementation has a problem when the input tree has multiple sub-trees. And I have realized that the problem is that I'm only using `x` but not `xs`. I wrapped my head around to think of the right approach and still figuring out. It will be very helpful if anyone has an idea for this.

Comment: As a hint, try writing an auxiliary function `[m (MyTree a)] -> m [MyTree a]` first (or use `sequence` from the libraries). Then think about how you can exploit that for `xs`. You will probably realize that you don't even need to handle the first element `x` in a special way, but you can directly use `check (MyTree v xs) =...`.

Comment: Thanks @chi. One more question! `xs` has a type `[MyTree (m a)]` and how do you feed that in an auxiliary function, `[m (MyTree a)] -> m [MyTree a]`? I'm getting it to the right way but bridging between these two is quite confusing.

Comment: That's correct, we need to turn `[MyTree (m a)]` into `[m (MyTree a)]`. We could use `map f` for that, for some `f :: MyTree (m a) -> m (MyTree a)`. Do we have such a function?

Comment: By "Nothing", do you mean the value `Nothing :: Maybe a`? Your function type should be `MyTree (Maybe a) -> Maybe (MyTree a)`; no general constraint `Monad m =>` is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `check` function is better known as a method of the `Traversable` class.

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable t where
  -- The main method
  traverse
    :: Applicative f
    => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
  traverse f = sequenceA . fmap f

  -- An alternative
  sequenceA
    :: Applicative f
    => t (f a) -> f (t a)
  sequenceA = traverse id

  -- (Mostly) legacy methods
  mapM
    :: Monad m
    => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
  mapM = traverse

  sequence
    :: Monad m
    => t (m a) -> m (t a)
  sequence = sequenceA
```

Specifically, `check` is `sequence` for `MyTree`. So we will get it if we write a `Traversable MyTree` instance. But let's first take a step back in two directions. `Traversable` is a subclass of both `Functor` and `Foldable`, and that is no coincidence. It's possible to implement both `fmap` and `foldMap` using `traverse`. But more to the point, the structures of `fmap`, `foldMap` and `traverse` tend to look almost identical! So let's start with those easier ones.

```
instance Functor MyTree where
  fmap f (MyTree a ts) = MyTree (f a) _
```

What goes in that blank? We have a list of subtrees and we need to generate a new one, so a good bet is

```
  fmap f (MyTree a ts) = MyTree (f a) (fmap _ ts)
```

Now the blank has type `MyTree a -> MyTree b`, so we just call `fmap` recursively:

```
  fmap f (MyTree a ts) = MyTree (f a) (fmap (fmap f) ts)
```

And we're done. Now let's turn to `Foldable`.

```
foldMap f (MyTree a ts) = _
```

Well, we're going to need to apply `f` to `a` to get a value in the monoid, then fold up the subtrees and combine the results. This ends up looking quite a bit like `fmap`, as promised.

```
foldMap f (MyTree a ts) = f a <> foldMap (foldMap f) ts
```

So now we get to `Traversable`. It's going to be pretty similar to `fmap`, but we need to combine results using `Applicative` operations *somewhat* like we combined `foldMap` results using `Monoid` operations.

```
instance Traversable MyTree where
   traverse f (MyTree a ts) = _
```

We have

```
a :: a
ts :: [MyTree a]
f :: a -> f b
```

Obviously, we're going to want to apply `f` to `a`. Following the pattern for `fmap` and `foldMap`, we're going to calculate `traverse (traverse f) ts`. So let's see where that gets us:

```
traverse f (MyTree a ts) = _ (f a) (traverse (traverse f) ts)
```

Now GHC will tell us that

```
_ :: f b -> f [MyTree b] -> f (MyTree b)
```

We need to take the `b` result from the first action and the `[MyTree b]` result from the second action and apply the `MyTree` constructor to put them together. We can do this using `liftA2`:

```
traverse f (MyTree a ts) = liftA2 MyTree (f a) (traverse (traverse f) ts)
```

---

Once you've gotten the hang of writing `Functor`, `Foldable`, and `Traversable` instances, doing so tends to get pretty dull. So GHC has an extension that lets the compiler write them for you.

```
{-# language DeriveTraversable #-}

module MyModule where

data MyTree a = MyTree a [MyTree a]
  deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

And you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and useful answer. I really appreciate it! @DanielWagner